# How to have a template class member that is derived from itself

Tags: c++

Example of what I am asking:

```
class a
{
    std::array<T, 5> arr; // T represents a class derived from class a
};

class b : public a
{
    b get(int i) { return arr[i]; }
};
```

How do I write it so arr must take a type that is derived from a.

Comment: Please don't spam tags. If you question isn't standard specific, there's no need to apply a standard specific tag.

Comment: please elaborate

Comment: The duckduckgoing term you are looking for is "Curiously Recurring Template Pattern", or CRTP for short.

Comment: The way you stated the question, it's impossible. You expect the size of `a` to be large enough to hold 5 objects that are at least as large or larger than `a`. In other words, that `S >= 5*S` where `S == sizeof(a)`